# Change color by scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, html

This [example](http://jsfiddle.net/4CwS4/1/) seems like to change red color into blue from bottom. But, I want to change the red color into blue from top position by scrolling. Could you show me the good solution? It's okay if there are using javascript.
Here is another [example](http://www.teslamotors.com/goelectric#range) what I want to. When you scroll down at this site, the gray line change into red.

```
<div id="scroll1"></div>
<div id="scroll2"></div>
```

Css part

```
#scroll1 {
   background-color: red;
   width: 50px;
   height: 800px;
}
#scroll2 {
  bacground-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 800px;
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. Do want to slowly change the bgcolor of your div depending on the scroll position? If yes why not using a gradient from red on top to blue

Comment: My code is just example code to understand what I mean. If you have solution with any method, could you show me the way?

Answer (score 0):

```
#scroll1{
   background-color:blue;
   width: 50px;
   height:800px

}
#scroll2{
   background-color:red;
   width: 50px;
   height:800px

}
```

According to approach used in example, this can be done by css. Just replace color.

Answer (score 0):

When you say scroll do you mean a gradual fade into the other color? Or do you want the change to happen instantly?

Either way you are going to be faced with javascript as CSS is quite limited when it comes to feature-rich UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to gradually change your colour you don't need two divs.

Create one div but with a gradient colour as the `background-color`.

The gradient is from red to blue, so when you scroll you don't need to change you CSS/JavaScript because the gradient will be different.

Look at my example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RuhW5/).

Answer (score 0):

Check this out . I guess this is what you want.

### html

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
   <div id="contents"> </div>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

### style sheet

```
#container{
    width:5px;
    height:400px;
    background-color: red;
    Position:absolute;
    border:1px #000 solid;
}
#contents{
    width:5px;
    height:400px;
    position:fixed;
    background-color: white;
     border:1px #000 solid;
}
```

### jquery script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").height(1000);
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var newSize = $("#contents").height() * (1 - $(window).scrollTop() /  ($(document).height() - $(window).height()));
      $("#container").animate({height:newSize+"px"},500);
    });
});
```

the demo is available here **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gTsHf/4/)**